# Real part of Exponential Sum

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, summation, exponential-function

I am working through a description of "Weyl differencing" and I am stuck on a certain part. $f$ is a polynomial, $N$ is a positive integer and we use the notation $e(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$. Then they assert:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\sum_{n = 1}^{N-\ell}e(f(n+ \ell) - f(n)) + \sum_{\ell=1-N}^{-1}\sum_{n = 1-\ell}^Ne(f(n+\ell)-f(n)) 
    = 2\text{Re}\sum_{\ell=1}^{N-1}\sum_{n = 1}^{N-\ell}e(f(n+ \ell) - f(n)) 
\end{align*}

I am not sure how we are able to make this step. I really don't even have any ideas on it. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall
$$  \cos(z) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z} + \mathrm{e}^{- \mathrm{i}z}}{2}  \text{.}  $$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\Re(e(x)) &= \Re(\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} x})  \\
    &= \Re( \cos(2 \pi x) + \mathrm{i}\,\sin(2 \pi x))  \\
    &= \cos(2 \pi x)  \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i}x} + \mathrm{e}^{- 2 \pi \mathrm{i}x}}{2}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}(e(x) + e(-x))\text{.}  
\end{align*}
So we see where the $2$ in front of the real part in the quoted formula comes from.  Additionally, we see that we are trying to figure out how the choices of indices in the two sums can be rearranged into pairs of $e$s with negated arguments.

In the first sum,
$$  \sum_{\ell = 1}^{N-1} \sum_{n = 1}^{N-\ell} e(f(n+\ell) - f(n))  $$
when $\ell = 1$, the inner sum gives
$$  e(f(2) - f(1)) + e(f(3) - f(2)) + \cdots + e(f(N) - f(N-1))  \text{.}  $$

In the second sum,
$$  \sum_{\ell = 1-N}^{-1} \sum_{n = 1 - \ell}^{N} e(f(n+\ell) - f(n))  $$
when $\ell = -1$, the inner sum gives
$$  e(f(1) - f(2)) + e(f(2) - f(3)) + \cdots + e(f(N-1) - f(N))  \text{.}  $$
By inspection, we can see that these are the $e(-x)$s to match the $e(x)$s in the first sum when $\ell = 1$.

Then, as $\ell = k$ in the first sum, the second sum gives the matching terms when $\ell = -k$ (as $k$ runs through $[1,N-1]$).